# How can I configure Yast to switch languages completely?

Tags: linux, opensuse, locale, yast

I have an installation of openSUSE 11.4 which was installed in German. I started Yast2 (which displayed in German, like "Netzwerkdienste") and switched the language to English under "System" -> "Sprache".

Yast2 downloaded some files, installed something and remained German ("Netzwerkdienste" can still be seen instead of, presumably, "Network Services").

I rebooted the machine, same result.

I un-installed the German Yast language pack. Yast2 persists in displaying in German.

I don't know how many of Yast2's screens are supposed to be translated, but I think it might only be the main screen that is in German. However, it is annoying. How can I change it?

Update:

I checked environment variables (for the root user). There are several variables that refer to language settings and all remain set to German.

```
declare -x LANG="de_DE.utf8"
declare -x LANGUAGE="de_DE.utf8"
declare -x LC_ALL="de_DE.utf8"
```

Shouldn't Yast2 have modified them?

Update:

I just started vi and it's also in German... does the language setting in Yast2 do anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

as user1024 says, cd into /etc/sysconfig, then find all files that have the pattern "de_DE" like

grep -r "de_DE" *

then edit each one changing the 'de_DE' to your preffered language

Answer (score 0):

Try to change settings in /etc/sysconfig/language file for system-wide, or ~/.i18n/language for individual user.

Comment: for english - update all entries in file from de_DE to en_US f.e.

Comment: You can edit posts.